# Many values for enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to sort the stores registered in segments. I want to have pre-registered segments for the user to choose, but they are many. It's a good idea to put everyone in an enum? There are over 15.

A Store is a model that have a type, the type is the segment. There is several types. The pre-registered are the several types in enum. I was thinking that the code will be dirty with all types in enum.

Comment: Be more specific and show some code. What are "the stores", what are "segments" / "pre-registered segments"? Also, explain your doubts. Why do you think it could be a bad idea to store it as an ENUM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you, really. You'll have people tell you that it's better to manage something like a field that can only have one of several values as an enum, and others would say that the field should be a string and you should validate it on your Segments model.

I'm partial to the latter.